# I'm trying to use EditText from Material Design - and I'm getting runtime exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I'm trying to use EditText from Material Design ( https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/ ) and I'm getting runtime exception.

I want to solve this problem

EditText Problem : When i try to open app with a regular EditText in a monitor and the app Crash [closed]

This's part of run log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fares.orderfood/com.fares.orderfood.SignInActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

    at com.fares.orderfood.SignInActivity.onCreate(SignInActivity.java:33)
```

/full

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.fares.orderfood, PID: 5512
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fares.orderfood/com.fares.orderfood.SignInActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
    at com.fares.orderfood.SignInActivity.onCreate(SignInActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
```

my java line 33

```
edtName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);
```

My java file full:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fares.orderfood.model.User;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public
class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtName, edtphone,edtpassword;
Button signinbtn1,cancel1;

@Override
protected
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

////////////////Text Input///////////////////
    edtName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);     /// this line (33)

    edtpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
    edtphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
```

my style file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>

             <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceHeadline2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline2</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceHeadline4">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceHeadline5">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
             <item name="textAppearanceOverline">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline</item>
         <!--  // Librarty material.io/design // -->

    </style>
```

add new my xml 
this my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/loginPageBackgroundColor"
    tools:context=".SignInActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/store"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="122dp"
            android:text="@string/signin"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- input Username  -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="fares"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <!-- input Username  -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtphone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_phone">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="0988123344"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- input Password  -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtpassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="1234"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <!-- input Button  -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- input Button signin -->
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/signin"
            app:backgroundTint="#A8A8A8"/>

        <!-- input Button cancel -->
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"

        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/signbtn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/signbtn"
        android:text="@string/text_cancel" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Please, I need help

Comment: Post your xml layout file. edtName is probably declared as a `TextInputLayout `

Comment: change 
edtName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);
to
edtName =(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);

Comment: I need to see the xml, but probably you have declared a TextInputLayout with the id R.id.edtName but in your code you are trying to cast to EditText     (edtName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName); ) so isn´t possible.

Comment: @ManuelMato 
I added code as the above code with the problem

Comment: @abdelazizrefaat
Also the same error
`edtName1 =(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);`

Comment: @ivanWooll
 I added code as the above code with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also the same error

```
You are casting TextInputLayout into EditText which is not possible, instead of this please try to cast TextInputEditText into EditText it will resolve your problem.
```

my java code

```
public
class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText edtName, edtphone,edtpassword;
    Button signinbtn1,cancel1;

    @Override
    protected
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    ////////////////Text Input///////////////////
        edtName =(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);

        edtpassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
        edtphone = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
```

You have to give the id to TextInputEditText like this instead of TextInputLayout. It will resolve your problem:

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/loginPageBackgroundColor"
    tools:context=".SignInActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/store"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="122dp"
            android:text="@string/signin"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- input Username  -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="fares"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <!-- input Username  -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_phone">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtphone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="0988123344"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- input Password  -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtpassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="1234"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <!-- input Button  -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- input Button signin -->
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/signin"
            app:backgroundTint="#A8A8A8"/>

        <!-- input Button cancel -->
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"

        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/signbtn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/signbtn"
        android:text="@string/text_cancel" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @faras please check the XML I have updated here. this is what causing problem in your case

Comment: my xml above 
` I added code as the above code with the problem `

Comment: I have updated my answer please copy my xml and paste in your xml then try

Comment: wow The problem is already solved, I understand
Thank you so much :)
@Black4Guy